# How to implement NAT in MuleSoft Anypoint VPN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, nat

Limitations Anypoint VPN does not support these features and configurations:

- Network Address Translation (NAT)
- IPv6
- IKEv2 with policy-based VPNs
- A single VPC with both AWS Direct Connect and Anypoint VPN connections
- Advertising a default route (0.0.0.0/0) over BGP or static routing

Has anyone found a solution for VPN connections to external systems that require NAT. We have requirement to connect to internal MQ system through a VPN that requires NAT, from external systems (in this case from MuleSoft's CloudHub).

Answer (score 1):

What @aled mentioned above will work as long as you have presence in AWS. That way you can push traffic over your own AWS VPC and NAT from there on. Still, I would probably NAT inside my own DC.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [AWS Transit Gateway](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/tgw-about) so connectivity is managed at the Transit Gateway level instead of using Anypoint VPN. In that way you are independent of any Anypoint Platform limitations, only bound by AWS limitations.